# delete multiple tsv files unwanted columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder contains 500 tsv files, I need to modify all of them.

This is the original data looks like:
[image: original tsv]

I would like to remove some imfos that I don't need, for example I would like to keep the part I circled and remove the parted X out
[image: What i want]

I already removed the comment parts off by using the following codes:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = "All_TSV_Files"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith(".tsv")]

c=0
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file), 
                     comment='#', 
                     header=None, 
                     sep='\t',engine='python',error_bad_lines=False)

    #save it as txt file
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(path, f'admin{c}.txt'),index=False,header=False)
    c+=1
```

now I also need to remove the first two columns, so the result would be like this :
[image: result expecting]

The current txt file looks like:

```
Precision,_,
agriculture,_,
(,_,
PA,_,
),_,
and,_,
information,_,
technology,_,
(,_,
IT,_,
),_,
are,_,
closely,_,
interwoven,_,
.,_,
The,_,
```

I need to change the "," to " " space.

Comment: what does your df look like?

Comment: I just posted down below. @drum

Answer (score 0):

my current df looks like

```
1-1,0-7,1677112,_
1-2,9-10,A,Project[1]
1-3,11-14,new,Project[1]
1-4,15-27,kernel-based,Project[1]
1-5,28-36,learning,Project[1]
1-6,37-46,algorithm,Project[1]
1-7,47-53,called,_
1-8,54-60,kernel,Project[2]
1-9,61-67,affine,Project[2]
```

I need to remove the first 2 columns, makes it to :

```
1677112,_
A,Project[1]
new,Project[1]
kernel-based,Project[1]
learning,Project[1]
algorithm,Project[1]
called,_
kernel,Project[2]
affine,Project[2]
```

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: Please add this in your question. it would be better

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by removing first 2 columns.

**Following line of code should work for you**

```
df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

**The complete should be like this:**

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = "All_TSV_Files"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith(".tsv")]

c=0
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file), 
                     comment='#', 
                     header=None, 
                     sep='\t',engine='python',error_bad_lines=False)

    df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1]], axis=1, inplace=True)
    #save it as txt file
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(path, f'admin{c}.txt'),index=False,header=False)
    c+=1
```

**To replace comma with space try following codes**

`df = df.replace(',',' ', regex=True)`

**OR**

`df = df.replace(',',' ', regex=True, inplace=True)`

**OR**

`df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', ' '))`

Comment: How about if I also want to change the comma to space?  df.replace(',' ' ')   is that correct?

Comment: You should do something like this `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',',' '))`

Comment: it gave me error ``` AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values! ```

Comment: It didn't make any changes. I think the comma just to separate each column, so its not in the actual value.  Can I change to separate them with space instead of column?

Comment: If possible then share the output so that I can check

Comment: I just add it into my question. please take a look. @Sabil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236414/discussion-between-sabil-and-kimi-shui).